# Calculating difference between two java.sql.Timestamp shows negative value

Tags: java, timestamp

I am calculating the difference between two timestamps which is in the following format

> 2013-07-22 05:24:24.77

I am using the following method to calculate the difference between two timestamps

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date resDate = sdf.parse(responseData.getTimestamp().toString());
Date reqDate = sdf.parse(requestData.getTimestamp().toString());
System.out.println("response-->"+responseData.getTimestamp());
System.out.println("request-->"+requestData.getTimestamp());
System.out.println("diff-->"+(resDate.getTime()-reqDate.getTime()));
```

The difference between two timestamps is negative in the following cases. For example

> Response date : 2013-07-22 05:24:24.77
>
> Request date  : 2013-07-22 05:24:24.663

Result is :

> diff-->-586

it should subtract something like this **"770-663"** instead it subtracting the timestamp as  **"77-663"**.

Can anyone please suggest what changes I should make or is there any other way to do it??

Thanks in advance

Comment: 77 means 77, not 770. (i.e. it is 77 ms past, not 770 ms past). So in your example, request date is *after* response date and it is normal that the difference is negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SSS` in SimpleDateFormat means the number of milliseconds, not fractional second, that is for SimpleDateFormat 663 > 77. But `Timestamp.toString` formats timestamp in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff` format, where `fffffffff` is fractional second. Use`java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(str)` for parsing what `Timestamp.toString` produces